# Better way to find an element within a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, domdocument

I am looking a better method than "find" to find all the elements within an element:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="test">
      Test
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="test">
      Test
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="test">
      Test
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is structure and and I have jquery of table as $table

I am willing to do something like this:

```
$table.find('.test');
```

Find is a very expensive call. I need a better way to do it. I know I can do it with direct selectors like this:

```
$('table .test');
```

But I am looking for an alternative for find which performs better. Find performs really bad especially in IE.

Comment: try testing it yourself: http://jsperf.com/

Comment: If there were a better way to do exactly what find does, jquery would use that way.

Comment: why do you need this, and aren't you using jquery ?

Comment: I have tried jsperf.com. Its a really good tool.

Comment: What's wrong with `$('table .test');`?

Comment: @SergeS: I am using jquery and jquery find performance is not good.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: Never think that jquery provides you with a best solution.

Comment: IMO, the table is a drag itself. unless you are really using it to tabulate data.

Comment: There are always a lot of test case on jsperf. This one for instance: [jQuery Sizzle vs jQuery find transversal](http://jsperf.com/jquery-sizzle-vs-jquery-find-transversal/5)

Comment: @emphaticsunshine Never assume that IE is going to perform well.

Comment: @j08691: I gave you a scenario about problem and it is not exactly what happens. I have access to tableObject and there can be multiple tables in a page. That's why I asked specifically for that

Comment: @emphaticsunshine - Actually your "scenario" mentioned no such thing. Perhaps you should be more clear on your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` is slow in IE because IE does not implement a native `getElementsByClassName`.  The fastest solution is apply knowledge of your DOM structure to the function that selects the elements.  It is less flexible but always will be the fastest solution.  In this case, it looks like the only elements that have the `test` class are `td`:

```
var rows = $table[0].rows, cells, i, j, numRows, numCells, result = [];
for(i = 0, numRows = rows.length; i<numRows; i++) { //Iterate over the table's rows
    cells = rows[i].children;
    for(j = 0, numCells = cells.length; j<numCells; j++) { //Iterate over the cells in the row
        if(cells[j].className == "test") { //Won't be valid if the cells have more than one class
            result.push(cells[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example.  Like I said, you sacrifice flexibility for speed, so you may need to tweak it to adapt to your particular structure but the principle remains.

Comment: But in browsers that *do* have `gEBCN` (or `querySelectorAll`) this will be much slower. It's often best to let jQuery find the quickest way, IMO.

Comment: I agree. Direct dom manipulation is faster in IE. jQuery selectors make it slower

Answer (score 3):

The biggest thing you can do is to improve the selector you are using:

```
$table.find('td.test');
```

Providing an element name speeds up the selection significantly. This is especially true in versions of IE before IE9, which lack the `getElementsByClassName` method.

If you have `getElementsByClassName`, this won't offer a significant improvement. If you don't, however, the improvement will be massive. jQuery has to select every element that *might* match, then test to see if it has the relevant class present. If you provide `td`, it will only test `td` elements. If you don't, it has to test *every* element, which will obviously take much longer.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use

> ```
> document.getElementById('myTable')
> ```

on

> ```
> <table id="myTable">
>   <tr>
>     <td class="test">
>       Test
>     </td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td class="test">
>       Test
>     </td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td class="test">
>       Test
>     </td>
>   </tr>
> </table>
> ```

Will be fastest as possible.

Answer (score -1):

I made a jsperf to test `$('.test', $('#my_table'))`  vs  `$('table .test');`

http://jsperf.com/find-vs-direct

It looks like `$('.test', $('#my_table'))` is the winner

Comment: That is a pointless case, in one you are using the `id` the other you are just using `table`.  `id` will always out perform `table`.  And more importantly, you don't have anything with that ID, so you're getting back nothing.

Comment: This is less true (in fact, completely false) if [you do a fair comparison](http://jsperf.com/find-vs-direct/4).

Comment: dude... there is no $("#my_table") so it will obviously perform better...try now

Comment: lol thanks, i guess you're right, i fixed that now. And i don't see how it's pointless because i wouldn't call that common knowledge